# problems sending bytes greater 0x7F python3 serial port

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port

I'm working with python3 and do not find an answer for my little problem.
My problem is sending a byte greater than 0x7F over the serial port with my raspberry pi.

example:

```
import serial

ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")

a=0x7F

ser.write(bytes(chr(a), 'UTF-8'))
```

works fine! The receiver gets 0x7F

if a equals 0x80

```
a=0x80

ser.write(bytes(chr(a), 'UTF-8'))
```

the receiver gets two bytes: 0xC2 0x80

if i change the type to UTF-16 the receiver reads

0xFF 0xFE 0x80 0x00

The receiver should get only 0x80!
Whats wrong! Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 specification says that words that are 1 byte/octet start with 0.  Because 0x80 is "10000000" in binary, it needs to be preceded by a C2, "11000010 10000000" (2 bytes/octets).  0x7F is 01111111, so when reading it, it knows it is only 1 byte/octet long.

UTF-16 says that all words are represented as 2 byte/octets and has a Byte Order Mark which essentially tells the reader which one is the most-significant octet (or endianness.

Check on [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for full specifications, but essentially you are moving from the end of the 1 byte range, to the start of the 2 byte range.

I don't understand why you want to send your own custom 1-byte words, but what you are really looking for is any SBCS (Single Byte Character Set) which has a character for those bytes you specify.  UTF-8/UTF-16 are MBCS, which means when you encode a character, it may give you more than a single byte.

Before UTF-? came along, everything was SBCS, which meant that any code page you selected was coded using 8-bits.  The problem arose when 256 characters were not enough, and they had to make code pages like IBM273 (IBM EBCDIC Germany) and ISO-8859-1 (ANSI Latin 1; Western European) to interpret what "0x2C" meant.  Both the sender and receiver needed to set their code page identifier to the same, or they wouldn't understand each other.   There is further confusion because these SBCS code pages don't always use the full 256 characters, so "0x7F" may not even exist / have a meaning.

What you could do is encode it to something like codepage [737/IBM 00737](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_737), send the "Α" (Greek Alpha) character and it should encode it as 0x80.

If it doesn't work, t'm not sure if you can send the raw byte through pyserial as the write() method seems to require an encoding, you may need to look into the source code to see the lower level details.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer! But what specification is the one to be used in this case. I just want to send 0x80-0xFF as one byte. UTF-8/-16 obviously not!

Comment: I will try your proposal. Why I need an SBCS is because I have to communicate with a device with a fix codepage. The communication consists of a string with a xor-checksum. The checksum can be greater than 0xF7.

Comment: @ ergonaut
 I have no luck! python3 + pyserial doesn't know any codec instead of UTF-x or ASCII! 
If I use python 2 it works perfect:


'#!/usr/bin python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import serial
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")
ser.baudrate=115200
a=0x80
ser.write(chr(a))
ser.close()'

I'm just looking for the equivalent in phython 3! Perhaps anyone knows how to!

Comment: Can you just change the receiver to understand the new encoding?

Comment: The receiver is a terminal like HTerm for testing!

Answer (score -1):

```
a=0x80

ser.write(bytes(chr(a), 'ISO-8859-1'))
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.